# Infinite loop on do while

Tags: loops, while-loop, integer

I'm trying to do a simple method that ask for a number, but I'm having troubles with the condition, here is my code:

```
private static int rows(){
    int w = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
    System.out.println("What is the number of rows?");
    if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        w = sc.nextInt();
        if (w <= 0){
            System.out.println("Error: the rows can't be 0 or negative number.");
        }
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println("Error: please only use digits.");
    }
    }
    while (w<=0);
    return w;
}
```

So, when I introduce a negative number or zero the code works fine, but if I try to introduce a letter or a invalid character like a dot or comma, the program enter in a infinite loop repeating this:

```
   System.out.println("What is the number of rows?");
   System.out.println("Error: please only use digits.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not refreshing `w`'s value. Re-enable the use to enter a new value for `w`. Something like:

```
int w = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("What is the number of rows?");
    if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        w = sc.nextInt();
        if (w <= 0){
            System.out.println("Error: the rows can't be 0 or negative number.");
        }
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println("Error: please only use digits.");
        sc.next(); // Clear default input on invalid input
        continue; // Restart the loop so it gets newer value again
    }
}
    while (w<=0);
    return w;
```

Comment: that's great, thanks a lot, now works perfectly, my professor told me that i should avoid recursion, so i was trying to do with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

`w` only gets changed in the case of `sc.hasNextInt()`. If you enter a letter / invalid character, `w` never gets changed, and your loop cannot end.

Comment: yeah, i know that, but how i can fix it?

Comment: @Stark: I don't know the Java API by heart (I'm more a C++ guy), and I'm not in a mind of looking up the details of the `Scanner` class and what it generates. But since you are asking for *one* value, it seems that it's not much use of looping in the first place?